# How to select second value in drop using Katalon Chrome Extention?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, chrome, katalon

[image]

[image]

I'm trying to make Katalon chrome extension to click the **dd/mm/yyyy** language.
But the problem is when I record the click on **dd/mm/yyyy** Katalon records

```
xpath=(.//*[normalize-space(text()) and normalize-space(.)='Select Language'])[2]/following::li[1]
```

Now for this, when the test case is run, it selects the **Select Language** value

BUT, if I select **mm/dd/yyyy** from the drop-down Katalon records

```
xpath=(.//*[normalize-space(text()) and normalize-space(.)='English (UK) - dd/mm/yyyy'])[2]/following::li[1]
```

And now when I run the test case, it will select **mm/dd/yyyy** and not **dd/mm/yyyy**

It seems the selection is offset by 1.

Answer (score 0):

How about we enter the xPath ourselves using li tag and text() ?

For Example -:

```
//li[contains(text(),'English (UK) - dd/mm/yyyy')]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to take xpath manually and place it in the xpath. I've tried it for Selenium IDE and it worked.

If not try to get the text.

```
driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[contains(text(),'English (UK)')]"));
```

> Please define the xpath properly, I haven't added it in here properly